# Python - sort wrt second argument

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I have a list, which I wish to sort. List is made of items with two elements each. I wish to sort wrt to second element only. Thus, I am almost sure that

```
L = [[4,2],[5,2]]
sorted(L)
```

won't do the job.

How to proceed? I come through answers but did not understand what could apply to problem.

Thansk!

Comment: There are many more here like that here on SO.

Comment: I spotted this question, did not have a clue whether it was also a possible syntax for sorted (not only max), or how to write it properly. thanks anyway for tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(L, key=itemgetter(1))
```

Returns the sorted list `L`, sorted by `key` the second item in each element of `L`.